# home page appears on all routes with react-snap

Tags: reactjs, seo, prerender, react-snap

i am using react-snap to pre-render pages with react-helmet and it works fine but i ran into two problems

- first: home page appears on top of all pages and in all routes
- second: meta tags of home page does not update on other components and i think this issue
  is related to the first one

here is my index.js:

```
import { hydrate, render } from "react-dom";
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { RecoilRoot } from "recoil";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
// import worker from "mocks/browser";
import { ToastContainer } from "components/shared/uikit/toast/ToastContainer";
// import "swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css";
import Loader from "./components/shared/uikit/loaders/loader/Loader";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import "./configs/i18n";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
if (rootElement.hasChildNodes()) {
    hydrate(
        <RecoilRoot>
            <ToastContainer>
                <Suspense
                    fallback={
                        <Loader
                            customSize={60}
                            suspense
                        />
                    }
                >
                    <BrowserRouter basename="/">
                        <App />
                    </BrowserRouter>
                </Suspense>
            </ToastContainer>
        </RecoilRoot>,
        rootElement
    );
} else {
    render(
        <RecoilRoot>
            <ToastContainer>
                <Suspense
                    fallback={
                        <Loader
                            customSize={60}
                            suspense
                        />
                    }
                >
                    <BrowserRouter>
                        <App />
                    </BrowserRouter>
                </Suspense>
            </ToastContainer>
        </RecoilRoot>,
        rootElement
    );
}
```

and here is my snippet from package.json:

```
 "reactSnap": {
        "puppeteerArgs": [
            "--no-sandbox",
            "--disable-setuid-sandbox"
        ]
    },
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this, I'm having the same issue but only with some routes

Comment: unfortunately no. i recommend you if you are in the start of the project try to use next.js cuz honestly react-snap is kinda outdated